# How to avoid this message warning "Maximum update depth exceeded..." on NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

on NextJs i not understand, how useEffect work. What i need to do, to stop of receiving this warning message
"Maximum update depth exceeded":

The Code bellow is the page, that call a component ListContainer, this page add a item to container.

The page JSX:

```
    import { useState } from "react";
import AppLayout from "../components/AppLayout";
import ListContainer from "../components/ListContainer";

export default function componentCreator(){


  
    const [item,setItem] = useState([])   

/* add item to container */
    function addItem(){

        let newItem = item
        newItem.push({
            produto: 'Skol 350ml',
            preco: '1200,00',
            quantidade: 'cx c/ 15 unidades'
        })
        setItem(newItem)

    }

    return (
        <AppLayout>
            <ListContainer items={item} setItems={setItem}/>
            <div className="productcardbuttonshow" onClick={() => addItem()}>ADICIONAR</div>
        </AppLayout>
    )
}
```

Bellow the component that handle the items, remove or add. But it works, but on console trigger warning messages about update.
Component ListContainer.jsx:

```
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
export default function ListContainer(props){

    const [html,setHTML] = useState(null)
    const [item,setItem] = useState(props.items)
  
/* refresh html container */
    useEffect(() => {
        const itemHTML = item.map((itemmap,id) => {
            return (
                <div id={id} onClick={() => delItem(id)} className="itemProposta">
                    {itemmap.produto} - {itemmap.quantidade} - R$ {itemmap.preco}
                </div>
            )
        })
        setHTML(itemHTML)
    })

/* remove item from container */
    function delItem(id){
        let itemlist = props.items
        itemlist.splice(id,1)
        props.setItems(itemlist)
    }

    return (
        <>
        {html}
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting into an infinite loops of renders. This code is responsible:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const itemHTML = item.map((itemmap,id) => {
            return (
                <div id={id} onClick={() => delItem(id)} className="itemProposta">
                    {itemmap.produto} - {itemmap.quantidade} - R$ {itemmap.preco}
                </div>
            )
        })
        setHTML(itemHTML)
    })
```

This callback inside `useEffect` will run after every render, because there is no dependency array. That means after every render, `setHTML(itemHTML)` is called. And even if the constituent objects of the array `itemHTML` are same, a new reference of the array is created. A new reference is created because `.map()` returns a new reference of the array. And although render and update works correctly, infinite rendering is happening.

Consider adding a [dependency array](https://www.google.com/search?q=useEffect+dependency+array+react&sxsrf=ALiCzsb_Q1qgFlRw6L4jp8deE3Lteehx2g%3A1656173715397&ei=kzS3YuLsF_rb4-EPsoyp4AU&ved=0ahUKEwiigvjv_8j4AhX67TgGHTJGClwQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=useEffect+dependency+array+react&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIICAAQHhAWEAoyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBY6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6CggAEOQCELADGAE6BAgjECc6BAgAEENKBAhBGABKBAhGGAFQyANY7wdg6ghoAXABeACAAZ8BiAHnBZIBAzAuNZgBAKABAcgBEcABAdoBBggBEAEYCQ&sclient=gws-wiz) to `useEffect`. For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
/* function body */
},[props.items]);
```

Now `useEffect` callback only runs if `props.items` reference changes.

**Side note (unrelated to your question)**:
In the below code,

```
  function addItem(){

        let newItem = item
        newItem.push({
            produto: 'Skol 350ml',
            preco: '1200,00',
            quantidade: 'cx c/ 15 unidades'
        })
        setItem(newItem)

    }
```

You should do `let newItem = [...item]`, otherwise you are not creating a new reference of `item` array and `setItem(newItem)` is basically useless in that case.